# Paypal Subscription Next due date payment solution?

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway, paypal, paypal-ipn

I created a paypal subscription in my merchant account. But i have problem on next due date. it like this...

i created the paypal subscription on 14 jan 2013 and set one day trail period. (this is daily subscription)

In my paypal account subscription detail page it shows 15 jan 2013 as next due date. That is correct because i setup a one day trail period. i wait and see to get daily subscription in 15 jan 2013 (due date).

However payment is made on 16 jan 2013. Now i have problem..

I want to know if i setup a subscription rule in 2013/01/14 with one day trail period. **So when i get first payment. is it beginning of day on 2013/01/15 or end of day on 2013/01/15**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal attempts to collect recurring payments from subscribers on the day after the previous
billing cycle or trial period ends. Billing cycles can be daily, weekly, monthly or yearly,
depending on the terms of the original subscription.

So the first payment happens when they first subscribe, then the next payment occurs the day after the first subscription period runs out...

Any delay otherwise is probably processing time (it can take a little while for payments to clear...)

I'm guessing after you created your plan you tried it out by subscribing... so you paid on the 14th for a 1 day trial that was over on the 15th... then the next payment happens the day after that billing cycle (the 16th) when it charges for the next period.

Information taken from the paypal pdf here https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_websitepaymentsstandard_integrationguide.pdf  Which I don't blame you for not finding... I had to download 2 pdfs before that one that kept telling me the document had moved and sent me to the next one until I finally got the right one.